# Displaying SQL data from multiple tables

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008

I have two tables that hold information needed to display time clock interaction in an excel sheet. The data will need to update with every time clock interaction. I joined the two tables and it was pointed out to me that data duplication is a big no no. Looking for a more simple solution than to do a join everyday so I can have recent interactions. Once I can get the SQL end set up, I can handle the excel side.

Table info:
From the dbo.employees table I need the ID, Last_Name, First_Name
From the dbo.employeetimecardactions I need ID, ActionTime, ActionDate, ShiftStart, Action Type.

ID is the common column between the two tables of course.

If my JOIN statement is needed I will supply, but seeing as the data duplication is a problem I would like to start fresh with NO prior code brought into it.

Also any additional information needed can be supplied if I know exactly what is needed

END RESULT- Excel File that I can share with the powers that be. Contains all recent time clock interactions. Also it would be nice to be able to search by date or employee but that should be an Excel function I would think, and not absolutely necessary

Comment: Why not just write an SQL Query to tab delimited flat file?
Something like
SELECT Emp.ID, Emp.FirstName, Emp.LastName, Action.Date, Action.Time,.....
FROM dbo.Employees LEFT OUTER JOIN
       dbo.EmployeeTimeCardActions

Comment: Let me just google that sentence real quick. I guess I erased the part where I said I have very little knowledge in SQL

Comment: thank you for elaborating. I will give it a shot and see what I come up with

Comment: Oops - should'a included this on the FROM clause:

FROM dbo.Employees E LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.EmployeeTimeCardActions A ON E.ID = A.ID

Comment: What is the A and E all about? Identifying tables?

Comment: Yep, that gives you a great shortcut in Select to just refer to each table element of dbo.Employees as E.<field>   likewise the action table elements as A.<field>

Comment: Nice. Thank you for that. Simple is always better in my mind

Comment: I have had other projects that took me away from this, but I am back at it.   Typed out: "SELECT Employees.EmployeeID,Employees.First_Name,Employees.First_Name            FROM Employees E LEFT OUTER JOIN EmployeeTimeCardActions A ON E.Employee ID+A.EmployeeID"        No dice. Doesn't like that syntax. SELECT  throws "Multi part identifier cannot be bound" on all columns and FROM throws "An execption of non boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected" on E.EmployeeID+A.EmployeeID

Comment: Sorry that is a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the names of the two tables and correct appropriately, this is based on the first part of this thread and later comments:

```
SELECT E.EmployeeID, E.First_Name, E.Last_Name, A.ActionTime, A.ActionDate, A.ShiftStart, A.ActionType
FROM Employees E LEFT OUTER JOIN
     EmployeeTimeCardActions A ON E.EmployeeID=A.EmployeeID
```

Here's a WHERE clause to include date. Please check your DB for date format to use:

```
="WHERE ActionDate BETWEEN '" & TEXT(A2,"mm/dd/yyyy") & "' AND '"&TEXT(B2,"mm/dd/yyyy")&"'"
```

The formula is in cell C2
[image: From worksheet]

Comment: I might have misunderstood and wrote it backwards, I would still think it'd work but I will take a second look at straightening it out.

Comment: Action_Type is the exact column name

Comment: ...then you can use A.Action_Type.    Please confirm all the data element names (i.e. is it E.EmployeeID or E.ID?).

Comment: dbo.Employees: EmployeeID, Last_Name, First_Name                   dbo.EmployeeTimeCardActions: EmployeeID, ActionTime, ActionDate, ShiftStart, ActionType

Comment: Edited the above to reflect what you just gave

Comment: Thank you. I have the join query running in excel. Now I will be working on that, I am aiming to type in a date in a box and then running the query. I am trying to display only relevant entries instead of all, but I do need all of the old entries. All of the fun stuff.

Comment: When you're building the query you could add WHERE (ActionDate < 'yyyy-mm-dd')

Comment: If I do that then I have to go back in and change that every time the excel sheet gets used. This is more of a make and forget situation. I will never use this, I am just the IT guy charged with making it work

Comment: You can use the date in the box typed in for what goes in yyyy-mm-dd.
The query is just a string where you can just append the WHERE clause, isn't it?

Comment: Id like to show you the code I have so far but I am under an answer ban for not answering questions I guess. If there is any way I can get around that I will do it

Comment: Your query did get the data into the sheet so that is done at this point but its returning all those results. I should be able to write that WHERE but at this point I will have to figure out these damn text blocks so I can point to them inside the WHERE

Comment: WHERE Date BETWEEN #" & DateMin & "# AND #" & DateMax & "#

Comment: I have something that looks like that without the added &s and #s but it doesn't seem to know the difference between data columns and the text boxes.